# How to do animate over a scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to do an animation with jQuery.
Using the .animate I know you can have a duration of time but I wanted to have a duration of pixels scrolled. 
I have seen this on some websites, that an effect occurs over a certain amount of pixels scrolled.
--For clarification, jQuery animate is like this:
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
The duration is in seconds, though.
I would like to know a way to achieve the same effect but with a duration of pixels scrolled.
For example, something fades in from 50 to 100 pixels scrolled but NOT that a fade starts when you hit 40px. 
If you scroll down, this has it: http://squarespace.com/home/overview/

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Some examples of sites which use this effect would be a great help.

Comment: you will need scrollspy js. Have a look at this http://davidwalsh.name/js/scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for - I guess... Try this fiddle to get started:

http://jsfiddle.net/pu1yLe4u/4/

Good Luck

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    if (window.pageYOffset > 20) {
        $('.moveme').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');

    } else {
        $('.moveme').css('transform', 'rotate(360deg)');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: this is just starting an animation once 20 pixels have been scrolled. i want to have an animation occur slowly over, say, 50 pixels. thanks

Comment: @LoriMiller You can add more code to change rotate degree incrementally with increase in each pixel... This code can be improved but will give you an idea of how to do it... http://jsfiddle.net/pu1yLe4u/12/